# How to terminate the grep pipe after first match

Tags: c, grep

Im trying to execute the following code in my C program but it seems that the -m1 switch is unable to terminate the pipe. As a result the program keeps reading the entire 16 GB file. Any help would be appreciable.

```
char *cmd=NULL;
cmd = malloc (200);
if (cmd != NULL) {
    strcpy (cmd, "sudo hexdump -v -e '");
    strcat(cmd,"\"");
    strcat(cmd,"%010_ad |");
    strcat(cmd,"\"");
    strcat(cmd," 100000/1 ");
    strcat(cmd,"\"");
    strcat(cmd,"%_p");
    strcat(cmd,"\"\"");
    strcat(cmd,"|\\n");
    strcat(cmd,"\"");
    strcat(cmd,"' -s 2437150492 /run/SDdownload.dd | grep -m 1 -E -o ");
    strcat(cmd,"\"");
    strcat(cmd,"single_install Secure cloud storage and file sharing");
    strcat(cmd,"\"");
    strcat(cmd,">./files/Sync.com/installation.txt");

    printf("Command -> %s\n",cmd);
    system(cmd);
```

Comment: What happens when you run the same command line from the shell (i.e. not in your C program)?

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: personally I would use `popen`, read lines and try to match them without grep and exit when first occurrence is found.

Comment: Could you post the output also

Comment: The command that I ran on the shell is: 
hexdump -v -e '"%010_ad |" 4096/1 "%_p""|\n"' -s 2437150492 /run/SDdownload.dd | grep -m 1 -E -o "single_install Secure cloud storage and file sharing"

Comment: there is no output. I am writing the first match to the file but the command keeps running in the background